# Unexpected behavior when DOM structure is modified and re-rendered in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have the following code which is built using react.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div id="content">
            .....
        </div>          
    </form>               
</div>
```

Here, a third party library updates **DIV#content** on regular basis. However, On submission of the form, I get to wrap the **DIV#content** with another DIV from my code. Please find the it below after the modification on submission:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div id="contentWrapper">
            <div id="content">
                .....
            </div>
        </div>          
    </form>               
</div>
```

But as soon as the **DIV#content** is wrapped by another DIV, third party library stops working. Can anyone tell me why it stops updating the **DIV#content** once the DOM structure is modified despite the fact that the **DIV#content** element is still available to library.

Note: React is not throwing any error about the DOM structure is changed but just the library stops working.

[Edit]: Here is the way I am rendering using react

```
render() {
  var returnIt;
  if (useDivOne) returnIt = (<div id='initial'></div>);
  else returnIt = (<div id='modified'></div>);
  return (returnItj);
}
```

Comment: Depends a lot on what the other library is doing, and how you're wrapping the div. One possibility is that rather than wrapping the existing DOM node, you're creating a new one with the same content. If your third party library is holding a reference to the original node rather than finding it every time, it won't have a reference to the new `DIV#content`

Comment: Could you add a React code?

Comment: @nAz I have added the example react code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When React is rendering it's not re-using the old DOM element. So your library still has a reference to the old DOM reference and not the new one that react is recreating when it re-renders. Since your library isn't primed for react, you could go about doing this in a sort of round about way, by guaranteeing that the dom element you pass to your library never gets re-created:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    // this makes sure yourDiv is ALWAYS visible inside your
    // component
    if(!this.yourDiv.parentNode) {
        this.refs.libContainer.appendChild(this.yourDiv);
    }
}

render() {

    // you will pass a reference to yourDiv to your library and it will
    // refer to that. YourDiv is NEVER re-created so this DOM element
    // lives forever and your library remains happy
    if(!this.yourDiv) {
        this.yourDiv = document.createElement('div');
        this.yourDiv.className = 'specialDiv';
        this.yourDiv.innerHTML = 'hahahaa';
    }
    return <div ref="libContainer"></div>;
    // .... or sometimes return this
    return <div className="wrapper"><div ref="libContainer"></div></div>;
}
```

And you would pass your library a reference to `.specialDiv` - note that we're completely stepping over how react renders the DOM here and that this approach is only really viable when fixing a problem where react is interfering with what you're trying to accomplish - so if you implement this I suggest making a new react component as a wrapper around your library so that all the "ugliness" to make the library react friendly can be contained in 1 component.

Comment: Whenever react re-renders, if it creates new DOM reference, then library should not be able to update the element at all. However, it is able to do if I just manipulate anything without changing the structure of DOM and re-rendering but not when the structure is modified by wrapping with a new div. Thanks.